# Search bar with indexing content

Tags: javascript, html, search, input

I want to add search bar but how to indexing content on the page? Should I add value to the for example div or id too or in js script?

```
<form role="search" action="/search" target="_top">
  <div>
    <input class="..." type="search" name="q" required="" aria-label="search input" placeholder="Search" value="">
    <button type="submit" aria-label="search button"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to learn how to do it and how to use it with more than 100 pages. I don't understand the process of adding and searching text/value on the static page.

Comment: You would have to build a spider that indexes your pages and you use that index to do the searching.

Comment: Spider? How it works?

Comment: It walks through the pages and stores data about it. Plenty of information out there.

Answer (score 0):

nah. most of website not do search by indexing content on page, its indexing database. because content coming from data on database. you can figure what happend in this simple code, it will be a good practice for you.

```js
const db = ['aa','ab','ac','ad']; // try to type one of them

const n_resLand_ = document.getElementById('resLand');

function search_db(val){
  
  let result_ = [];
  
  for(let i=0; i<db.length; i++){
    if( db[i].includes(val) ){
      result_.push(i);
    }
  }
  
  if( result_.length ){
    n_resLand_.innerHTML = 'found on index: '+ result_.join(',');
  }else{
    n_resLand_.innerHTML = 'no result';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" oninput="search_db(this.value)" />
<div id="resLand"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, so how it works? There is a page html/css/js + database for ex. mysql?

Comment: its depending on how the database's data is formatted. in this example we using array.

Comment: Could you write any case? The simplest way to do it.